# .htaccess redirect adding a hash while keeping the query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using mod-rewrite in a .htaccess how do you add a hash to a url while keeping the query string in front of it? Everything i have tried appends the query string to the end, which then makes it part of the hash.

This is what i'm trying to do:

```
http://example.com/order_now?utm_campaign=eblast082814
```

redirected to

```
http://example.com/index.php?utm_campaign=eblast082814#order_now
```

Here is my current non-working .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ /index.php?#$1 [QSA,R,NE,L]
```

Above is wrongly redirecting to

```
http://example.com/index.php?#order_now&utm_campaign=eblast082814
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like query string is added right after `#order_now` by default.

Here's a solution (by capturing query string and add it manually)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ /index.php?%1#$1 [R,NE,L]
```

Comment: I just needed to remove the [QSA] from your code (otherwise it appends the query string to the end again) and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry i forgot to remove `QSA` from my answer. You're welcome, glad it work. Don't forget to validate my answer if it was helpful